# Why is my route getting only null parameters?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, null, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to get this route working in my MVC3 application but the action method always
gets null parameters.

The general idea is that my route has a compulsory parameter "category" and an optional parameter "city". The probable Request URLs would look like this:

```
   /Map/SelectCategory/Restaurants
   /Map/SelectCategory/Restaurants/Washington
```

This route is meant to return JSON data because it will be used as a web service, that contrary to the standard /Map/Category action that I defined after this that is for regular 
webpage and works fine.

So, my route is defined in Global.asax as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute(    // Map It! Controller
            "MapSvc",  // route name
            "Map/SelectCategory/{catID}/{city}",   // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Map", action = "SelectCategory", city= UrlParameter.Optional }
         );    

 .. Here a route for /Map/Category/{id} ..
 .. Here a route for /Map/Placemark/{id} ..
```

As far as I know I can omit 'catID' in the route definition because it is automatically bound that being non-optional, right? Tried by defining it but same outcome.

Last but not least, my Action in the Controller is defined as this:

```
 public ActionResult SelectCategory(string catID, string city)
 {
     IEnumerable<Models.Placemark> list;
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(city)) {
        list = doThis();
     } else {
        list = doThat();
     }
     return Json(list);
 }
```

Now I placed a breakpoint on the first statement of the action but when I request the URL as stated in the route (/Map/SelectCategory/Restaurants) I see that both the category and city parameters are NULL, in this case I expect the category parameter to be "Restaurants".

**Solution**
Note: Because I don't have 100 points of reputation I would have to wait 6 hours to post the answer and I really got to go so here it is.

**Thanks** @tsegay who got me in the right direction. All other routes defined in Global.asax had explicit URLs with parameters but the problem was caused because the default route (the standard one created in the empty solution template) was too greedy for this case:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
 );
```

I moved it at the end of the list of routes in Global.asax and now the problem is gone! Thank you very much for getting me in the right direction.

Comment: Is "MapSvc" route the first in the routes list on Global.aspx, I think some other route is overriding it. Posting more information from Global.aspx will help to better understand the situation.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to omit "catID" from the `defaults` argument in the MapRoute method. This should work... just making sure, the action method argument is also called "catID"? Your route parameter names have to match your action method argument names (case insensitively).